# OctoberCMS: how to setup user account activation by email in Rainlab.User plugin?

Tags: email, activation, octobercms

I'm using Rainlab.User plugin with user activation via e-mail.

By default user receives an email with activation link "http://examples.com/register". So there is no activation code in it. How it is supposed to work at all?

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you forgot to set the url parameter on the page where the Account component is placed?

The page url needs something like: `register/:code?`

And the component settings must reflect that with the 'Activation Code Param' set to `code` as a normal string.